# Need to download package and all dependancies for armhf debian

Tags: debian, apt, arm

So, I need to download a package and all its dependencies for armhf Debian. The thing is that I am stuck on an Ubuntu machine. How can I download all of this stuff?

Answer (score 1):

---

Example : https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/joe → → All the dependencies are listed : The red dots. Be aware that the dependencies can also depend on some packages : Click the dependencies for a check. ... "armhf" : See the list at the bottom of the page. Click armhf ,,,, and you will come to a page with links.

---